# angular timepicker not working in angular application

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use:

[angular-timepicker](https://github.com/Geta/angular-timepicker)

**Source: index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/angular-dragula/dist/angular-dragula.min.css" redl ="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/angular-ui-bootstrap/src/position/position.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular-dateparser/dist/angular-dateparser.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular-timepicker/src/angular-timepicker.js"></script></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>


  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Directive:**

```
  <input type="text" dn-timepicker ng-model="time" />
```

With this line, all that I really get is an input field with no timepicker.
I have included script reference to angular UI bootstrap and angular-dateparser as well.

Comment: Are there no JavaScript errors? Are all the referenced scripts loading correctly?

Comment: Yes, there are no javascript errors and the scripts are loading correctly.

Comment: I'm either blind... or you've renamed the file... but where is you Angular reference (which leads back to my first point)?

Comment: ionic.bundle.js has angular build in it.

Comment: Anyone??? I have been trying stuff but not able to get it working

Comment: Grasping at straws here... but, it's possible that the timepicker's script gets loaded before the UI CDN gets downloaded?

Comment: No, I changed the CDN to load ui locally and that made no difference either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the dnTimepicker in your app modules depencies :

In your app.js :

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['dnTimepicker']) ...
```

Comment: My bad. Not that I am new to this but since it was nowhere mentioned, I assumed there isn't a need to add module dependency. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check my design: https://github.com/jmloveyj/angularjs-timepicker.
It is very simple and easy to polish.

AngularJS directive of timepicker and datepicker with IOS alarm style. You can fit it in your mobile html5 app for ios style animation feel timepicker. It is a base. You can decorate your own style timepicker by modifying css.
[timepicker demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eH8Z.png)

Comment: You should answer this question here, so that other people who will visit this page will also learn.